# Why is there NoneType when should be Label?

Tags: python-2.7, ttk

Just the question from the title "Why is there NoneType when should be Label?" And how to solve it to be able to modify the label text in the onComboBoxChange?

```
label1 = Tkinter.Label( frame, text = '1.0' ).grid( row = 4, column = 5 )

nums = ( 'one', 'two' )
v1 = Tkinter.StringVar()
v1.trace( 'w',
    lambda name, index, mode, sv = v1: self.onComboboxChange( sv, label1 ) )
ttk.Combobox( frame, textvar = v1, values = nums,
    state = 'readonly', width = 14 ).grid( row = 2, column = 1 )

def onComboboxChange( self, sv, label ):
    label.config( text = 'smth' ) # ------------- why do I get NoneType here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
label1 = Tkinter.Label( frame, text = '1.0' ).grid( row = 4, column = 5 )
```

`.grid` doesn't return anything. You want to save the actual widget before calling `grid`.